# OracleSQL: Auto Increment depending on another column (weak entity modelling)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

I have a table called "Project" in my database and a table called "Milestone". The primary key of "Project" is a column called ProjectID. The relation "Milestone" has a primary key called "Number" and a foreign key referring to the project it belongs to.

As I insert a new entry into "Milestone" I would like the primary key "Number" to be incremented automatically, but in relation to the project the new milestone belongs to. The idea is basically the following:

```
       Milestone
ProjectID  |   Number
   69             1
   69             2
   69             3
   420            1
   420            2
   666            1
   420            3
```

Is it possible to realize this in OracleSQL using a trigger when inserting values inside the "Milestone" table?

Answer (score 0):

First off, naming a column `NUMBER` in Oracle is an INCREDIBLY bad idea, as this is the name of the base numeric type. I'll assume you're going to be smart and call this `PROJECT_LINE` instead.

You can use a compound trigger to accomplish this. In the `BEFORE STATEMENT` trigger point you capture the max PROJECT LINE for all projects (because of course in the BEFORE STATEMENT section you don't know *which* project you're looking at), then in the `BEFORE EACH ROW` trigger point you assign the max value + 1 to the new PROJECT_LINE, and update the line of project max values:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MILESTONE_TRG
  FOR INSERT ON MILESTONE
COMPOUND TRIGGER
  TYPE NUMBER_MAP IS TABLE OF NUMBER
    INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  tblMAX_PROJECT_LINE  NUMBER_MAP;    -- store max PROJECT_LINE, indexed by PROJECT_ID

  BEFORE STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
    tblMAX_PROJECT_LINE := NUMBER_MAP();

    FOR aRow IN (SELECT PROJECT_ID,
                        MAX(PROJECT_LINE) AS MAX_PROJECT_LINE
                   FROM MILESTONE
                   GROUP BY PROJECT_LINE)
    LOOP
      tblMAX_PROJECT_LINE(aRow.PROJECT_ID) := aRow.MAX_PROJECT_LINE;
    END LOOP;
  END BEFORE STATEMENT;

  BEFORE EACH ROW IS
  BEGIN
    :NEW.PROJECT_LINE := tblMAX_PROJECT_LINE(:NEW.PROJECT_ID) + 1;
    tblMAX_PROJECT_LINE(:NEW.PROJECT_ID) := tblMAX_PROJECT_LINE(:NEW.PROJECT_ID) + 1;
  END AFTER EACH ROW;
END MILESTONE_TRG;
```

I won't vouch for the efficiency of doing this. Also, multiple simultaneous INSERTs may collide. You'll need to put a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint on (PROJECT_ID, PROJECT_LINE), trap the key violation exception which may occur on your INSERT statement, and retry the INSERT.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment and a very good clarification. Regarding the "number" column, fortunately for me, I did name the column "number", though I did not use the english word for it, but rather another language. However, the code you have shown me is not completely working. When I try to insert a new Milestone entry, I get the error "trigger is invalid and failed re-validation".

Comment: As with all code on StackOverflow you may need to do a little debugging to get it to work in your situation. Apparently there's an error in the code for your trigger. To find out what the error is you can execute the following: `SELECT * FROM ALL_ERRORS WHERE OWNER = 'trigger owner' AND NAME = 'trigger name' ORDER BY SEQUENCE`, replacing `'trigger name'` with the name of your trigger and `'trigger owner'` with the schema in which the trigger was created. Best of luck.